# Encrypting files with crypto++ using RSA

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, crypto++

I wanted to encrypt a large binary file using crypto++ library with asymmetric encryption(RSA) algorithm. I have searched for working example and couldn't find it. 
Is it possible? What kind of things should i consider when i implement it using this library

Comment: asymmetric encryption used or for key exchange or for sign data. it not used for encrypt data. for this select some symmetric algoritm

Comment: As mentioned by RbMm, asymmetric encryption is usually used to secure a communication channel, such as ssl (asymmetric handshake, afterwards uses symmetric encryption for performance) or to sign data. This link provides examples how to use crypto++ library. https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography#Keys

Comment: If i choose AES as a symmetric algorithm, which mode is more "standard", CBC or CFB?

Comment: Also see [encrypt file hybrid encryption scheme](https://www.google.com/search?q=encrypt+file+hybrid+encryption+scheme). If you can switch to Diffie-Hellman over integers or elliptic curves, then checkout [Discrete Logarithm Integrated Encryption Scheme](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Discrete_Logarithm_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) (DLIES) or [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) (ECIES).

Comment: It is possible! ... not considered secure, as the iteration of homomorphic cryptosystems as RSA reveals private information, so https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki is silent about your question . If you want to do it: find out the usable data block size per encryption block (E.G. mode OAEP has 42 bytes overhead), slice your stream accordingly and concatenate encrypted blocks in the output stream. If you are into security I would suggest ECIES; Inventor Master Shoup is into true security, might be the reason, why his proposal didn't make it to the standard ;) https://www.shoup.net/papers/iso-2_1.pdf